# com.firebase.ui.authui class not found whenever I try to import it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using this code to do so but com.firebase.ui.authui is not present in the library. Where can I get it or How can I use it in the code. Please help.

```
startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setProviders(
                                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Have you added Firebase-UI dependencies in your build.gradle file?

Comment: more details required!!

Comment: Please edit your question and add this lines of code in there.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh Check now

Comment: @AlexMamo Please have a look now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, please add the following line in your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.2.0'
```

When using Firebase authentication together with [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library, both dependencies must be added to your build.gradle file.

Comment: Thanks for the help 
But When I add this 
Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
This error comes up and it doesn't do anything when clicked

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: I understand. Clean up your project and try again.

Comment: YES: Rebuild, even 'a few times' to resolve this BTW :8.0.2

Comment: @ShimonRothschild I just updated my answer accordingly.